# Java RoundingMode HALF_UP doesn't round up as expected

Tags: java, double, rounding

So I have this code

```
public String getRounded(double amount) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(df.format(amount));
    System.out.println(amount);
    return df.format(amount);
}
```

I've added those two lines to see the difference and this is an example of what they display.

The output is this for example:

1.25

1.255

Why does this happen? Isn't the point of HALF_UP to round up? I've tried with CEILING and it does round up, although that's not what I want in this case.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

`double` is lying to you.  `System.out.println` is lying to you.

`amount` is not exactly 1.255.  It is actually `1.25499999999999989341858963598497211933135986328125`, which is less than the exact real number 1.255.

Rounding that with HALF_UP returns, correctly, 1.25.

If you care about fine distinctions like this, you will need to use BigDecimal from the beginning.

Comment: Worth noting that `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(amount))` will tell the truth.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you