# Rounding error down when not adding a round number using RoundingMode HALF_UP in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

consider below method:

```
fun main() {
    var costs = 0
    var transactionFee = 1.325

    var total = (costs + transactionFee).toRoundedUpDouble()
}

fun Double.toRoundedUpDouble(fraction: Int = 2) =
    BigDecimal(this).setScale(fraction, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble()
```

I want a number with 2 decimal after the comma, rounded up from 5. e.g. 1.325 becomes 1.33. This works when I add a round number, but not when I don't:

Output:

```
5.00 + 1.325 becomes 6.33 = good
5 + 1.325 becomes 6.33 = good
1 + 1.325 becomes 2.33 = good

1.325 becomes 1.32 = NOT GOOD
0 + 1.325 becomes 1.32 = NOT GOOD 
0.00 + 1.325 becomes 1.32 = NOT GOOD 
0.000 + 1.325 becomes 1.32 = NOT GOOD
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47781393/java-roundingmode-half-up-doesnt-round-up-as-expected) doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Why doesn't the mentioned thread answer your question, though? Everything is right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47781393/java-roundingmode-half-up-doesnt-round-up-as-expected) doesn't answer your question, but I it really does.

As mentioned in that thread, double literals lie to you, and `println` as well.
To know the actual value that these literals give you, you can use `BigDecimal` this way:

```
println(BigDecimal(1.325))     // 1.3249999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
println(BigDecimal(0 + 1.325)) // 1.3249999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
println(BigDecimal(5 + 1.325)) // 6.32500000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

If you want accurate results, use `BigDecimal` from the start, and make sure to initialize them with strings, not double literals:

```
fun main() {
    var costs = BigDecimal.ZERO
    var transactionFee = BigDecimal("1.325")

    var total = (costs + transactionFee).roundedUp()
    println(total) // 1.33
    println(total.toDouble()) // 1.33
}

fun BigDecimal.roundedUp(fraction: Int = 2) = setScale(fraction, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```